# Program not rerendering after setstate is called.react

Tags: reactjs, state

On all my functions, my progam rerenders when I call `setstate`.
I added a new function to delete tags and after I call `setstate` the program does not gets rerenderd.
My JSON get updated but the clicked tag is not deleted in browser.

I also tried to use `this.forceUpdate();` but that still don't work.

This is my code

```
{Object.keys(props.tags).map((key, i) =>
              <div style={{backgroundColor: "#0753ad", height: "20px", borderRadius: "3px", display: "inline-block", padding: "5px", lineHeight: "0px", float: "left", color: "white", marginRight: "5px", fontSize: "12px"}}>
                {props.tags[i].name} <i className="fa fa-cog"></i> <i className="fa fa-trash" key={i} onClick={() => props.ondeletetag(props.index, i)}></i>
              </div>
            )}
```

This is the function:

```
ondeletetag(row: any, nr: any) {
    const array = this.state.fields.columns;
    array[row].tags.splice(nr, 1);
    this.setState({ fields: { columns: array } });
    console.log(this.state.fields.columns);
  }
```

My class looks like this:

```
class CrmConnectorColumns extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.moveCard = this.moveCard.bind(this);
    this.oncheck = this.oncheck.bind(this);
    this.ontextupdate = this.ontextupdate.bind(this);
    this.ondeleterow = this.ondeleterow.bind(this);
    this.onaddnewrow = this.onaddnewrow.bind(this);
    this.ondeletetag = this.ondeletetag.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      isSaving: false,
      canSave: false,
      errorColor: "danger",
      fields: { columns: {} },
      deleteModalActive: false
    };
  }
```

And the render method:

```
{Object.keys(columns).map((key, i) =>
             <CardWithDnD
             key={columns[i].index}
             indexnr={i}
             moveCard={this.moveCard}
             oncheck={this.oncheck}
             ontextupdate={this.ontextupdate}
             ondeleterow={this.ondeleterow}
             ondeletetag={this.ondeletetag}
             {...columns[i]}
           />
            )}
```

I expect that my program rerenders after the setstate and not only update the state.
Does anyone have an idea why my program not rerenders?
FULL CODE SANDBOX: https://codesandbox.io/s/n1064qjwkm

Comment: The code you are rendering does not seem to be accessing any value in your state, how are you sure that your component is not rerendering ?

Comment: because the state gets updated, but the tag itself is not deleted in browser

Comment: Can you share the code where you are passing the props?

Comment: @NabilShahid check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

The tag which you are deleting exist as the child of any component? If it does you need to update the state of the parent component to see the changes such as removed tag from the view which will re render all the things in the view without refreshing the page.

Comment: The tag array is a child a parent array, I update the state of the parent already

Comment: Do you get the value of "nr: any" in the function ondeletetag(row: any, nr: any) everytime it is mapped? log the value of console in the function. I don't think the value will be print everytime as you call the function on click of the <i>.

Comment: I did log it inside the function and Its printed everytime I call the function

Answer (score 0):

Have you written shouldComponentUpdate function in your component, Because if you return false here you updation lifeCyle will be stopped.

According to react life cycle, The updation lifecycle will always call render() method if there is a change in the state unless you stop it in shouldComponentUpate or you have extended pureComponent.

Comment: No I haven't one

Comment: @Darkinfore Can you post your complete code or provide a link for online editor?

Comment: Yes, here is my full code, but I dont get it working on this fiddle https://codesandbox.io/s/n1064qjwkm

Comment: @Darkinfore There is no problem with the set state rather `array[e.target.id].tags.splice(e.target.key, 1);` is not doing any change to the array. first length of the array is 5 and after splice also the length of array is 5 so there is no effect even after setState. Coming to this code `array[e.target.id].tags.splice(e.target.key, 1);`  e.target.key is undefined. Please check it and try to alter the array

Comment: I updated the code that removes the tags but just not in browser.

Comment: The state gets updated, also the length of array stays 5, only the tags array removes one element, Its a multidimensional array, inside the main array there is a tags array for each element

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making a copy of the tags array, remove the element from that one and then overwrite the existing array with the copy.

```
ondeletetag(e: any) {    
   var array = this.state.fields.columns;
   const newlist = [].concat(array[e.target.id].tags); // Clone array with concat or slice(0)
   newlist.splice(e.target.dataset.key, 1);
   array[e.target.id].tags = newlist;
   this.setState({ fields: { columns: array } });
}
```